# Dynamically create a folder with “button” on click through the Java server page/ Java

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to create an automatic directory (via "input button") through the JSP. For this purpose, I have followed the following code:

```jsp
<form action ="index.jsp">
<input type="button" name="systemDes" value="Build ">


<%
        String startTodir = request.getParameter("systemDes");
        String path="home/user1/Desktop/";
        File folderCreation = new File (path+"01");
            System.out.println("hello+2");
            if (startTodir != null){
            System.out.println("hello+1");
            folderCreation.mkdirs();
            }
    %>`
</form>
```

How to debug the above code for creating directory?

Comment: What is the issue? And your path seems to be wrong.

Comment: Path has been corrected.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Please suggest me how to debug the above code" ? the code for creating the directory is correct. It would create a new directory with the name "01".

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The path has been edited. If I use "!=null" condition then program does not create any folder. If I remove it then it creates but through the reload  not the submit button.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked!

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. I think, all of you write (use the servlet method)

Comment: Did you change the form action to ""? if you did then on submitting the form would trigger a page reload and pass the request parameter.

Comment: Yes I did. But I received the same error

Comment: Is the page reloading when you hit the button?

Comment: @Amardeep- Not reloading

Comment: I've tested it with an `<input type="submit">` and `<form action="">` in my case the page was reloading and the request parameter with `name="systemDes"` was also sent.

Comment: Hmm. You are right

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using scriptlets in JSP.

Instead, use Ajax:

- Create a servlet that will get the `request` parameter and create the folder
- Use ajax in the `onClick` of your button and make a call to the servlet.

If you still want to have the logic in jsp file, I would suggest changing `scriptlets syntax (<% ... %>)` to `declaration syntax (<%! ... %>)` and declare your file creation code in method say `createFile`. and use this method on button click. Your code is not working on button click because it seems `request.getParameter` is returning null and with this declarative syntax, this can be avoided

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page the request parameter `systemDes` is present so the `startTodir` is not null and the `if` is satisfied and the directory is created.

All you need to do is change to `<form action="">` this will reload the page when the submit button is hit and pass the `systemDes` parameter in the request.

This kind of code in JSP is not recommended, you should really consider writing a servlet to do the file creation.

The complete code is

```
<form action="">
<input type="submit" name="systemDes" value="Build ">
<%
        String startTodir = request.getParameter("systemDes");
        String path="home/user1/Desktop/";
        File folderCreation = new File (path+"01");
            System.out.println("hello+2");
            if (startTodir != null){
            System.out.println("hello+1");
            folderCreation.mkdirs();
            }
    %>
</form>
```